# How tomcat handles welcome-file-list mentioned in web.xml

Tags: tomcat

I am having an application where i have mentioned welcome file list like this

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>flows/login.htm</welcome-file></welcome-file-list>
```

So when i hit the URL of my application i.e. http://localhost:8080/demoApplication

Then it loads the welcome page i.e login page.
But in URL it shows only http://localhost:8080/demoApplication
not like http://localhost:8080/demoApplication/flows/login.htm

I want to show like this http://localhost:8080/demoApplication/flows/login.htm
.Basically by this URL "http://localhost:8080/demoApplication" its by passing one of my filter.

So how does tomcat handles the welcome-file-list, means how does it redirects user to it.
Or how do i get the URL like this http://localhost:8080/demoApplication/flows/login.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the URL to change then you need to send a redirect to the client. Otherwise, the client thinks that the server answered a request for `http://localhost:8080/demoApplication` rather than performing an internal-forward to `flows/login.htm`.

In version 8 and above, Tomcat has support for [configurable rewriting](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/rewrite.html). If you have an earlier version of Tomcat, or don't like the built-in rewrite capabilities, [Tuckey's urlrewrite](http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/) is very popular.

Comment: Thanks for replying, will look into this.